# Return True if a given string is present in a webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to create a script that can find a given string in a webpage if the string is in the webpage output True

I ve tried this

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re

page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://winesarts.com').read()

parsedpage = bs.BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')


text = parsedpage.find_all('facebook')

print(text)
```

[]

Comment: It looks as though it uses JavaScript to create the finished page. `BeautifulSoup` won't do that for you. Maybe look at using [tag:Selenium].

Comment: What is this `find_all` function?  You failed to include it.  What does your code do?  Where is that part that you expected to return a boolean value?  You seem to have done several things to avoid using the built-in **in** operator.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `'wine' in parsedpage.text`.

It outputs: `True`